# WPF not disposing viewmodel

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5, dispatcher

I am having an issue of memory leaks regarding WPF. I have a view model that is not being disposed.

I narrowed the problem to a method that is calling the database and updating the fields on the viewModel.

It goes like this:

```
public async Task RefreshAsync2(CancellationToken token = default)
{
        var data = await Mediator.Send(new GetDataQuery());

        if (data != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                ViewModelInfo = data;
            });
        }
}
```

And in this method the problem lies in the `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke` that is using an anonymous (lambda) method to capture "this".

I have to use Dispatcher because this refresh method could be called from another thread ie. a Timer.

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is wrong anyway. It would create a new Dispatcher for a (background) thread that does not already have one. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher?view=windowsdesktop-8.0):

> Gets the Dispatcher for the thread currently executing and creates a new Dispatcher if one is not already associated with the thread.

That is not what you want. Use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` or somehow pass the UI Dispatcher to the view model as parameter.

However, assuming you call

```
await RefreshAsync2();
```

from the UI thread, you do not need a Dispatcher call at all. This code should be sufficient:

```
public async Task RefreshAsync2(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var data = await Mediator.Send(new GetDataQuery());
    if (data != null)
    {
        ViewModelInfo = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: But as I stated in the question, this method can be called from another thread ie. another task, a background job or a Timer. So this is why I used Dispatcher.

Comment: Then using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is still wrong.

Comment: For a timer, use DispatcherTimer.

Comment: And what about other background job (task)?

Comment: As said in the answer: *Use Application.Current.Dispatcher or somehow pass the UI Dispatcher to the view model as parameter.*

Comment: Tried with Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke but with the same result. The problem still persist, "this" instance of VM is captured and held.